# Highlight file opens up file in a preview window functionality instead of double click

Tags: intellij-idea

Coming from a Visual Studio environment and Xcode environment, if you highlight a file on the project window (LHS), the file opens.  IntelliJ doesn't open a file until you double click it.

It's kind of a different feel since it opens it up in a new tab each time vs just using the last active window or a preview window to flip between files.  Is there a way to make it more like VS or Xcode that where highlighting the file actually opens the file in the current window?

Answer (score 0):

There is *Autoscroll to Source* option in the project view settings. Unfortunately it doesn't open the focused files in the current tab, but in new tabs.

I haven't found an option to change this behavior anywhere, but there is already a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125012) on IntelliJ's YouTrack asking for this, so feel free to vote for it :)

[image]